# Use multiple rerank query in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

Taking the reference from [re-rank query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/query-re-ranking.html#rerank-query-parser), how can we use multiple/complex re-ranking logic in rqq. Mentioning the example given in documentation :

```
q=greetings&rq={!rerank reRankQuery=$rqq reRankDocs=1000 reRankWeight=3}&rqq=(hi+hello+hey+hiya)
```

Suppose I have a Document of schema :

```
Document(id : String, count : Long)
```

For this I want to re-rank my documents based on below criteria as well:

1. bq - boost the document by 2 if "id" matches string "apple" - (id:"apple"^2.0)
2. bf - this should multiply the value of "count" by 3 for scoring - (mul(field(count),3))

How can we express these two conditions together in rq/rqq ?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do it, we can achieve this by using query function. We can compute score given by above two conditions(mentioned in the question) and sum them to get the final score.

```
{!rerank reRankQuery=$rqq reRankDocs=100 reRankWeight=2}&rqq={!func}sum(mul(field(count),3),query({!query v=$v1}))&v1=query(text:\"apple\"^2.0,0)
```